# Discrepancy when writing binary int array in C++, then reading in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, int, binaryfiles

I'm using C++ to write an int array to a binary file like so:

```
int * _row;
_row = new int[200];
// .. fill array

// outputs 8, so one integer should be 8 bytes long
cout << sizeof _row << endl;

ofstream fHandle;
fHandle.open("~/row.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
for (int ii=0;ii<200;ii++) {
  fHandle.write( (char*)&_row[ii], sizeof _row );
}
fHandle.close();
```

Now when I read it in MATLAB (as below), I don't get the original array.

```
fid = fopen("~/row.bin");
x = fread(fid, 'int32');
fclose(fid)
```

I realise I should use a data type consisting of 8 bits (such as 'int64'), but with 'int32' I at least get the right values. **However**, each value is read twice! I don't have any explanation for this. I end up with an array of size 400 (which makes sense since I'm reading smaller chunks). If I choose 'int64', I end with the right dimension, but the values are wrong.

Do you have any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fHandle.write( (char*)&_row[ii], sizeof _row );
```

This should be:

```
fHandle.write( (char*)&_row[ii], sizeof(int));
```

Since you want to write one integer inside each iteration of your for loop right?
Since `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time `sizeof row` only returns the size of a pointer (`int*`) which is 8 bytes on a 64-bit system (and 64-bit compile). `sizeof row` would only return the (byte-)size of the array if row would be a static array (in the form `int row[200];`). Since all of this is a bit tricky to explain, I wrote a small example on codepad: http://codepad.org/FdPfo62y , it uses 32-bit so the pointers are just 4 bytes in size. I used int16_t (which is 2 bytes in size) to show the discrepancy between the pointer and data type size.

You could also do the whole write without the for loop:

```
fHandle.open("~/row.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
fHandle.write((char*)_row, sizeof(int)*200);
fHandle.close();
```

Also, if you use explicit data type sizes in Matlab I would suggest you use them in C++ too, so with C++11 you could use `int32_t` instead of int.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly! Just out of interest, can you explain why `sizeof _row` yields 8?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, this is very useful!